# Typescript: what is the proper syntax for this interface?

Tags: typescript, interface

I'm following the docs but it seems my syntax is off from the interface examples. I'm testing this code on the playground at http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=5&ssc=9&pln=5&pc=23#code/FDCWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjaACA8gIwFZoN7BrEFEnnjQDOMAJgAqwD2ADnJAJ4BcaNsEAczLEAvsDHBkTcDTRNcPbHgC8BNJRrQGzNrE48A5BroA1RABsArtANoJUmU3PQAdOaYCAFPJwvjWxlZ2DgBKAG4QSWlZHwAmHnx1ajpA3U543kh+cAE7NFVE-20gvQ4MgwA3C2tY23top1d3Lzi-ZICdYNjwoA

```
// Example 1. 
// has a red lint on myProperty: "Unused label." 
// also a red lint on string: "string is a type but being used as a value"
interface Obj {
    {
        myProperty: string
    }
}
const obj: Obj = { myProperty: 'value' }
console.log(obj.myProperty); // console error: string is not defined


// Example 2: Works as expected
const obj2: { myProperty2: string } = { myProperty2: 'value2' }
console.log(obj2.myProperty2);
```

What is the proper syntax for the single property object defined in the interface above?

**Update 1**

Here is an example POST response from an API I'm working with, I'm curious what the best way to write an interface to model this would be:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
{
  "script_tag": {
    "id": 870402694,
    "src": "https://djavaskripped.org/fancy.js",
    "event": "onload",
    "created_at": "2019-10-16T16:14:18-04:00",
    "updated_at": "2019-10-16T16:14:18-04:00",
    "display_scope": "all"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name the container property as well like so

```
interface Obj {
  containerProperty: {
    nestedProperty: string;
  }
}
```

Or if you don't want nesting you can just define your interface like this

```
interface Obj {
  myProperty: string;
}
```